# Difference between Twitter Bootstrap and Bootmetro?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.0

I am working in cakephp framework and as i am familiar with the twitter-bootstrap and heard a new word bootsmetro which is similar to it .Can anyone explain me both concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot Metro is Windows 8 style web frame work .

Its build on top of bootstrap with extensive support for the Windows 8 App store .

For More extensive info - [BootMetro](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/)

Comment: So shall i consider this as twitter-bootstrap and use its functions? and can you please tell me a specific setup to put bootsmetro advantage in my project?

Comment: okie...thankyou so much....as now  i am now getting smwhat clearity in my vision...

Comment: Using bootmetro as a choice will really depend on the Project requirement .

Comment: If your project is somewhere related to App stores or around web stores , this can be a useful framework . Moreover if you are familiar with bootstrap than using bootmetro is no different . The syntax and classes are all same with different styling . So a little research into the css file will yield you good results

Comment: project is tottaly web based portal with lots of sliding steps dropdowns ,typeaheads and otherformfields

Comment: I ll prefer using Bootstrap

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24447/discussion-between-shail-and-jhanvi)

Answer (score 2):

BootMetro is a simple web UI framework to create web apps which simulates Windows 8 Metro user interface. BootMetro is built on top of Twitter Bootstrap. BootMetro by default does support all sorts of metro ui style. Look at this website it is built using ASP.NET MVC + BootStrap + KnockoutJS [TechCipher](http://www.techcipher.com/).

Also BootMetro by default does not have built in support for live tiles, but can be done look at this [example](http://csharptechies.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-tiles-with-bootmetro.html)

Disclosure: Please note that links provided are for my own websites

Comment: I don't think your answer really addresses the original question.